# Length Validation Testing Rails Test:Unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, tdd, testunit

I am just getting into Rails testing, and I am using the built in testing "language" as opposed to Rspec.  For the life of me I can't figure out why this is still failing.

```
test "product title is at least 10 chars long" do
    product = Product.new(description: 'yyy',
                          image_url: 'zzz.jpg',
                          price: 1)
    product.title = 'testitout'
    assert product.invalid?
    assert_equal ['title must be at least 10 chars long'], product.errors[:title]

    product.title = 'testitoutt'
    assert product.valid?
end
```

And here is the Product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, :description, :image_url, presence: true
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
  validates :title, uniqueness: true
  validates :image_url, allow_blank: true, format: {
    with: %r{\.(gif|jpg|png)\Z}i,
    message: 'must be a URL for GIF, JPG, or PNG'
  }
  validates :title, length: { minimum: 10 }
end
```

here is what my terminal is telling me.

```
1) Failure:
ProductTest#test_product_title_is_at_least_10_chars_long [/test/models/product_test.rb:62]:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-["Title is too short (minimum is 10 characters)"]
+[]


5 runs, 23 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: What is failing? Your `product.errors[:title]` should eq `["is too short (minimum is 10 characters)"]`

Comment: Nvm I figured it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm just learning this too, and here is what I found solved it.

The message in the assert line has to match what is outputed by Rails in the browser (minus the Title part).

So in the browser when your title is too short it flashes this error message:

[image: **Title is too short error message**]

So the text we can test for is:  'is too short (minimum is 10 characters)'

Make your assert_equal line:

```
assert_equal ['is too short (minimum is 10 characters)'], product.errors[:title]
```

Then your test will pass.